# appium - selecting the parent node

Tags: java, xpath, appium

I'm currently in a situation where I need to select the parent from a child. The child has an id but the parent doesn't. So this is actually one of the few solutions.

```
WebElement child = driver.findElement(By.id("books"));
System.out.println(child.getAttribute("name")); //prints correct node
WebElement parent = child.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
System.out.println(parent.getAttribute("name")); // error can't find element
```

Comment: The xpath statement should allow you to select an element that has a child with a given criteria (in your case an id).

Comment: Any idea why it won't work?

Comment: try something like  "//*[@id="books"]/.." in your first search. that says find any element with id="books" and then navigate to its parent.

Comment: What is the error it give you when you use ".." from the child element?

Answer (score 4):

In Appium, to select immediate parent node, you need to provide /..

E.g.
childElement Xpath = //android.widget[@text='name']

Parent Xpath expression:
mobiledriver.FindElement(By.xpath("//android.widget[@text='name']/..").click

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find element based on other element you need to use `.` at the start of xpath to select current node. This should work for you:

```
WebElement parent = child.findElement(By.xpath("./.."));
```

Comment: Already tried that but got the same result. It is an hybride app, could it be that this is the reason why it doesn't really work as it supposed to work?

Comment: Not sure. Shouldn't be the reason.